# Laravel 5 : Submit form doesnt work

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

I can't submit a form with laravel. Nothing even happens, no errors is shown. Page just stays the same as it was.

This is my route file:

```
Route::resource('/', 'WebsiteController');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

This is file with form:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
                {!! Form::open(['url' => '/']) !!}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group wow fadeInLeft">
                            {!! Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Your name *','id'=>'name']) !!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group wow fadeInLeft">
                            {!! Form::text('email',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Your email *','id'=>'email']) !!}
                        </div>    
                        <div class="form-group wow fadeInLeft">
                            {!! Form::text('phone',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Your phone *','id'=>'phone']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group wow fadeInRight">
                            {!! Form::textarea('message',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Your message *','id'=>'message']) !!}    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center wow bounceIn">
                            {!! Form::submit('Click Me!') !!}
                        </div>
                </div>    
                {!! Form::close() !!}

                @if ($errors->any())
                <ul class='alert alert-danger' style='list-style: none;'>
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
                @endif
            </div>
```

This is my CreateContactRequest file:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class CreateContactRequest extends Request {

/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
                    'name'  => 'required|min:3',
                    'phone' => 'required',
                    'email' => 'required|email',
                    'message' => 'required'
    ];
}

}
```

And finally, this is my store method in WebsiteController:

```
public function store(CreateContactRequest $request)
{
            $this->createContact($request);

}
```

Included files on top of the WebsiteController file:

```
use App\Contact;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateContactRequest;
use Illuminate\HttpResponse;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Request;
```

Any help is welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: You might need to tell the form builder that you want `POST` as the request method, i.e. `Form::open(['url' => '/', 'method' => 'post'])`.

Comment: I've tried , but everything is the same.. :( thanks anyway mate..

Comment: Have you checked your database to see if the record is being created?

Comment: Maybe also try `$this->createContact($request->all());`

Comment: Yes , db is empty... Want to add that even validation errors is not showing up , everthing stays the same when i click on submit button...

Comment: Thing is that this is contact form used on one page website, i maked create page now ,and everything works fine..,

Comment: Try this: `{!! Form::open(['url' => '/store']) !!}`

Comment: Some included js in the template may be preventing the form to submit.

Comment: can you show your Contact model and createContact($request) method

Comment: `private function createContact(CreateContactRequest $request)
        {
            $contact = Contact::create($request->all());
             
            return $contact;
              
        }`    createContact function

Comment: And contact model `<?php namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model {

 protected $fillable = [ 
        'name',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'message',
        'created_at'
    ];

}`